# NASM and GDB Symbols: "Can't find any code sections in symbol file."

Tags: gdb, nasm, ld

I am trying to get a simple example working from an assembly book I am reading. I am trying to get gdb to work with my simple assembly program that I am assembling with the NASM assembler. Below is the code, and the object file in elf format.

```
; Version         : 1.0
; Created Date    : 11/12/2011
; Last Update     : 11/12/2011
; Author          : Jeff Duntemann
; Description     : A simple assembly app for Linux, using NASM 2.05, 
;                   demonstrating the use of Linux INT 80H syscalls
;                   to display text.
; Build using these commands:
;   nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
;   ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
;

SECTION .data                    ; Section containing initialized data
EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg

SECTION .bss                     ; Section containing uninitialized data

SECTION .txt                     ; Section containing code


global _start                    ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
    nop                          ; This no_op keeps gdb happy (see text)
    mov eax,4                    ; Specify sys_write syscall
    mov ebx,1                    ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov ecx,EatMsg               ; Pass offset of the message
    mov edx,EatLen               ; Pass the length of the mesage
    int 80H                      ; Make syscall to output the text to stdout

    mov eax,1                    ; Specify Exit syscall
    mov ebx,0                    ; Return a code of zero
    int 80H                      ; Make syscall to terminate the program
```

and

```
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ objdump -s ./eatsyscall.o

./eatsyscall.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .data:
 0000 45617420 6174204a 6f652773 210a      Eat at Joe's!.  
Contents of section .txt:
 0000 90b80400 0000bb01 000000b9 00000000  ................
 0010 ba0e0000 00cd80b8 01000000 bb000000  ................
 0020 00cd80                               ...             
Contents of section .stab:
 0000 00000000 64000100 00000000           ....d.......    
Contents of section .stabstr:
 0000 00
```

I am using the following command to assemble:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
```

and I am using the following command to link:

```
ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
```

When I run GDB on the executable I get the following:

```
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ gdb eatsyscall 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/mehoggan/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall/eatsyscall...Can't find any code sections in symbol file
(gdb) quit
```

What do I need to do in addition to what I am doing above to get gdb to read the debug symbols specified to NASM with the -g flag?

FYI

```
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ uname -a
Linux mehoggan 3.0.0-12-generic-pae #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:37:17 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$
```

---

--Update--

Even if I take the 64 bit route with the following commands I am still having no success:

mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o -melf_x86_64
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ ./eatsyscall 
bash: ./eatsyscall: cannot execute binary file
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$ objdump -s eatsyscall.o

eatsyscall.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .data:
 0000 45617420 6174204a 6f652773 210a      Eat at Joe's!.
Contents of section .txt:
 0000 9048b804 00000000 00000048 bb010000  .H.........H....
 0010 00000000 0048b900 00000000 00000048  .....H.........H
 0020 ba0e0000 00000000 00cd8048 b8010000  ...........H....
 0030 00000000 0048bb00 00000000 000000cd  .....H..........
 0040 80                                   .
Contents of section .stab:
 0000 00000000 64000100 00000000           ....d.......
Contents of section .stabstr:
 0000 00                                   .
mehoggan@mehoggan:~/Code/AsmWork/eatsyscall$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `section .text` istead of `section .txt` ?`

That is:

```
SECTION .data                    ; Section containing initialized data
EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg

SECTION .bss                     ; Section containing uninitialized data

SECTION .text                    ; instead of .txt
```

Should work just fine afterwards in gdb and if you are on a x64 architecture, use the x64 flags.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am having the same problem as you. Almost literally. I'm working through the same example in the Duntemann book. (The only difference in the source code is that I changed part of the string from Joe to Bob whilst trying to confirm that differences I made in the source code had the expected effect on the compiled executable.)

What I've discovered is slightly curious. I have two computers and am working alternately on each one using a synched dropbox directory. The older machine is running Ubuntu Karmic, because that has the best support for much of the stuff in Duntemann's book. I tried to put Karmic on the new machine as well, but some stuff simply won't install on it because it's no longer supported. So I'm running Ubuntu Oneiric on it instead.

Here's the thing. I can compile and run the exes on both machines. But anything compiled on the Oneiric machine seems to lack symbol information that gdb/kdbg/Insight is happy to work with. The stuff compiled on the Karmic machine works fine. And once built on the Karmic machine and synched with Dropbox, gdb/kdbg/Insight will run THAT exe fine on the Oneiric machine.

So the problem appears to be the compilation process on Oneiric. It is missing or changing something that messes up the ability of the debuggers to work with it properly.

---

Here is a dump of the Karmic object file:

```
$ cat karmic.txt           

eatsyscall.o:     file format elf32-i38

Contents of section .data:
 0000 45617420 61742042 6f622773 210a      Eat at Bob's!.  

Contents of section .text:
 0000 90b80400 0000bb01 000000b9 00000000  ................
 0010 ba0e0000 00cd80b8 01000000 bb000000  ................
 0020 00cd80                               ...       

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00546865 204e6574 77696465 20417373  .The Netwide Ass
 0010 656d626c 65722032 2e30352e 303100    embler 2.05.01.

Contents of section .stab:
 0000 01000000 00000a00 02000000 01000000  ................
 0010 64000000 00000000 00000000 44001a00  d...........D...
 0020 00000000 00000000 44001b00 01000000  ........D.......
 0030 00000000 44001c00 06000000 00000000  ....D...........
 0040 44001d00 0b000000 00000000 44001e00  D...........D...
 0050 10000000 00000000 44001f00 15000000  ........D.......
 0060 00000000 44002100 17000000 00000000  ....D.!.........
 0070 44002200 1c000000 00000000 44002300  D.".........D.#.
 0080 21000000                             !...           

Contents of section .stabstr:
 0000 00656174 73797363 616c6c2e 61736d00  .eatsyscall.asm.
```

---

Here is a dump of the Oneiric object file:

```
$ cat oneiric.txt           

eatsyscall.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .data:
 0000 45617420 61742042 6f622773 210a      Eat at Bob's!.  

Contents of section .text:
 0000 90b80400 0000bb01 000000b9 00000000  ................
 0010 ba0e0000 00cd80b8 01000000 bb000000  ................
 0020 00cd80                               ...  

Contents of section .stab:
 0000 01000000 00000b00 02000000 01000000  ................
 0010 64000000 00000000 00000000 44001a00  d...........D...
 0020 00000000 00000000 44001b00 01000000  ........D.......
 0030 00000000 44001c00 06000000 00000000  ....D...........
 0040 44001d00 0b000000 00000000 44001e00  D...........D...
 0050 10000000 00000000 44001f00 15000000  ........D.......
 0060 00000000 44002100 17000000 00000000  ....D.!.........
 0070 44002200 1c000000 00000000 44002300  D.".........D.#.
 0080 21000000 00000000 64000000 00000000  !.......d.......

Contents of section .stabstr:
 0000 00656174 73797363 616c6c2e 61736d00  .eatsyscall.asm.
```

You can see that the two files are different (there are several extra bytes at the end of the non-working Oneiric file). And whatever nasm is doing on Oneiric is not playing properly with the debugger, it would seem.

Comment: Just to follow up on this:
I used Bless to edit the non-compliant .o file, and manually zeroed the 64 corresponding the final 'd' in the .stab section.

After rebuilding the exe with this manually-altered file, everything worked.

Is this 64 saying that it's trying to create a 64 bit object file? (My version of Oneiric is 32-bit.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine with current CVS version of GDB: "GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20111108-cvs", and also with GDB 7.2.

It sounds like "Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2" is broken in some way.

Answer (score 0):

try using section/segment .text instead of .txt or .code :)